# Fetching All Active Record from base repository ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am trying to fetch all ACTIVE items from a table using repository pattern actually and below is what I have tried. It's not working.

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAllActive()
{
    return this.Context.Set<TEntity>().Where(ex => typeof(TEntity).GetProperty("IsActive").Equals(true));
}
```

I know I could easily achieve this by fetching it from individual entity repository but to avoid repetition, I want it to be in the base repository.

I know it's possible, but I'm not yet that good at combining reflection with a lambda expression.

Comment: what you mean by *It's not working.*?

Comment: @Rahul, It's not returning active items.

Answer (score 0):

```
return this.Context.Set<TEntity>().Where(ex => ex.GetType().GetProperty("IsActive").Equals(true));
```